# SharePoint 2010: Additional default search crawled property on User Profile Search

Tags: search, user-profile, crawling, managed-property

I have used the following article to add an additional crawled propert to SharePoint 2010 user profile search. http://www.sharepointsteve.com/2010/10/making-custom-user-profile-properties-searchable-in-sharepoint-2010/

The crawled property is called NickName. This is setup, configured and searchable!

If i search using the following criteria "Nickname:Jon" i successfully return my user record as i have the nickname Jon populated. However if i just search "Jon" i get no results returned.

I have looked at the configuration for the Search Service, User Profile and for the search webparts but am unable to get this working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure, it makes any difference but a detailed thread from someone who faced similar issue. The person seemed to have contacted MS Support as well, so you'll see a lot many updates. Here's the [article](http://kgraeme.wordpress.com/2010/07/28/sharepoint-user-profile-custom-properties-keyword-search-problem/).

Comment: Thanks Nitin i resolved the issue using the post by adding mappings for the crawled properties to the ‘ContentsHidden’ managed property. I then needed to run a full crawl

Comment: Glad the post helped

Comment: This really helped even in SP 2013. Thanks for your answer.